# pip not installing all dependencies in setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

pip3: pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6) on Ubuntu

I'm installing a local package, but not all of the dependencies are being collected/installed.  The following is my setup.py file.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    required = f.read().splitlines()

setup(
    name='g_plotter',
    packages=find_packages(),
    #packages=['g_plotter', 'pandas'],
    include_package_data=True,
    """ install_requires=[
        'flask',
    ], """
    install_requires=required,
)
```

requirements.txt:

```
click==6.6
flask==0.11.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10.0
MarkupSafe==0.23
numpy==1.15.4
pandas==0.23.4
python-dateutil==2.5.3
pytz==2016.4
six==1.10.0
Werkzeug==0.11.10
flask-cors
```

Failure at:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Traceback

```
server_1  |   File "./g_server.py", line 21, in <module>
server_1  |     from g_plotter import Gparser
server_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/g_plotter/Gparser.py", line 4, in <module>
server_1  |     import pandas as pd
server_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

The failure is happening at this step in the Docker build.

```
Step 12/15 : RUN pip3 install ./g_plotter
 ---> Running in 7cc0957f23e6
Processing ./g_plotter
Requirement already satisfied: flask in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from g-plotter==0.0.0) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask->g-plotter==0.0.0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask->g-plotter==0.0.0) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask->g-plotter==0.0.0) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask->g-plotter==0.0.0) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->flask->g-plotter==0.0.0) (1.1.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: g-plotter
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for g-plotter: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for g-plotter: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-iu6t3zln/wheels/a5/fc/d6/bbda9e5e615cade7b93e6d32cfba9062e2b21ea5352d0c2be0
```

I also ran the pip install command directly on my host with the same results.  This is that output using the -vvv option and it doesn't show any the missing modules either.

Comment: What does `head -n 1 < $(which pip3)` return? This command will show you the she-bang line of your pip3 executable. If it points to your Python3.6 (system default) executable, then this pip3 will install packages in a location searched by that distribution's Python3.6 executable. If you want to use a different Python3.7 executable, you'll need to call that Python's associated pip executable. It is usually installed in the same directory as the Python executable itself.

Comment: I don't see any error in your last code snippet? It just seems incomplete.

Comment: @unutbu, it's #!/usr/bin/python3, but the problem was that I was updating the wrong setup.py file.

Comment: @Sraw, looks like it was cut off, but I found the issue which is that I was updating the setup.py in the wrong location.